# AFNetworking GET not working - (Invalid escape sequence around character 94.)

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

[manager GET:@"http://xml.memurlar.net/mobile/json/news/headlines.aspx" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

I am using latest *AFNetworking*. I want to get object from the link that I used above. But I get following error:

```
Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid escape sequence around character 94.) UserInfo=0x1203e950 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid escape sequence around character 94.}
```

Any solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah that API isn't returning a valid JSON structure.  The problem is right here:

> "KPSS\'de kim hangi oturuma girecek?"

That \ is not a valid escape character and needs to go.  What are you using to serialize that JSON?

Comment: i have no idea about server. i just want to use API by using afnetworking. but does not work as you see :/

Comment: Well that server is returning invalid JSON so obviously AFNetworking can't deserialize it.  You have two options: fix the server or remove the escape character from the JSON string before it gets fed to NSJSONSerialization.

Answer (score 0):

```
//do not use the default json serializer.
manager.responseSerializer=[AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```

Comment: i have already tried it but i get following response;
JSON: <7b0d0a09 224e6577 73223a20 5b0d0a09 097b0d0a 09090922 4944223a 20343636 3632332c 0d0a0909 .......>

Comment: <pre>    if([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSData class]])
        {
#ifdef DEBUG
            NSString *responString=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];// responseObject
            
            
            NSLog(@"reveived soap  from server  \n\n\n%@",responString);
#endif <code>